# What is the difference between the 5 Gevurot and 5 Chassadim

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism, chabad, chassidic-rebbe, chesed-kindness

I hear these concepts in Chassidus. What is the difference between the 5 Gevurot and 5 Chassadim?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the question, it sounds very interesting but I would like to clarify, what exactly are you asking? The main difference is that some are Gevurot, and some are Chassadim, so are you asking what's the difference between a Gevura and a Chesed? Do you just want a list of the 10 fingers of the soul?

Comment: A source for this would be good.

Comment: @RabbiKaii If you are going to answer this, please make sure you relate it to its source in terms of the Aleph-Beit, namely those letters which possess dual forms of plain and final letters. That this relates to the extension from the underlying  fundamental division of the 3 kavin of Right/Chesed, Left/Gevurah and Center/Tiferet. These are the concept of Father/Right Hand, Mother/Left Hand, Child/Sign of the Bris. That extension to 5 is the concept of Grandparents/the 5 digits of the right and left hand or foot.

Comment: @YaacovDeane please could you answer, you clearly know more about this than me, and I tend to focus on the prose explanations than the kabbalistic technicalities. In that light, I have a good source for the chassadim that I may put into an answer that would complement yours

Comment: @RabbiKaii I'll have to reflect on this a bit in order to compose an intelligible answer.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Pardes_Rimonim.1.2.1?lang=bi&with=all